# Ultra simple R for loop not working

Tags: r, for-loop

I cannot figure out what's happening here (R language):

```
a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
space = combn(a,2)
b = 0
for(j in ncol(space)){
 if(space[1, j] == space[2, j]){
   b = b + 1
    }
 }
```

I get b = 1, this shouldn't be 1. ¿any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this without any loop

```
combn(a, 2, FUN = function(x) +(x[1]==x[2]))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

If the above output is the expected, one way with `for` loop would be to initialize 'b' with `length` equal to the `ncol` of 'sample' and then loop through the sequence of columns in 'space'

```
b <- numeric(ncol(space))
for(j in 1:ncol(space)){
  if(space[1, j] == space[2, j]){
   b[j] = b[j] + 1
   }
}    

b
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

NOTE: In the OP's code the `for` loop is `j in ncol(space)`, which is of length 1 instead of looping through the sequence.

---

If we want the number of columns where both values are 1 or both are 0

```
sum(colSums(space)==2)
#[1] 6
sum(!colSums(space))
#[1] 10
```

Or using `table`

```
 tbl <- table(combn(a, 2, FUN = sum))
 tbl[names(tbl)!=1]

 # 0  2 
 #10  6
```

Using the OP's code (changed to `1:ncol(space)`)

```
 b <- 0
 for(j in 1:ncol(space)){
   #Note that here we are not differentiating whether both 
   #are 0 or both are 1
   if(space[1, j] == space[2, j]){
     b = b + 1
      }
    }
 b
 #[1] 16
```

But, suppose we do

```
 b <- 0
 for(j in 1:ncol(space)){
   if(space[1, j] == 1 & space[2,j]==1){
    b = b + 1
     }
   }
 b
 #[1] 6
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but why my own loop does not work? any idea? thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, but the above's output is not what I am expecting, just want to get the number of columns of matrix "space" where both rows take value 1 or where both rows take value 0.

Comment: @MarioMadrid But then your code is not reflecting that one.  Because `space[1,j]==space[2,j]` can be either 0 or 1.

Comment: But it does not make sense to me, let me explain. As I see it, everytime any of these two things happens (1 == 1 or 0 == 0), the if sentence executes, and b = b + 1. So I do not know why b ends up taking value of 1... thanks!!

Comment: @MarioMadrid  Based on your comment.  I updated the post.  Now, it has 10 cases where both values are 0 and 6 cases where both are 1.

Comment: Mmm... thanks but still really confused about why my loop does not work. I come from MATLAB programming and there it works perfectly...

Comment: @MarioMadrid Your loop didn't work because there is one element to which is looping i.e. the last column.  `ncol(space)` instead of `1:ncol(space)`

Comment: Oooooh... yeah, your last solution is the key... maany thanks!! I feel little like an idiot right now haha many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` function and `length` for the total count in each condition

```
# Both the rows having value 1
> which(space[1,] == 1 & space[2,] == 1) 
[1]  1  2  3  9 10 16
# Both the rows having value 0
> which(space[1,] == 0 & space[2,] == 0) 
[1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
# Row 1 having value 1 and row 2 having value 0
> which(space[1,] == 1 & space[2,] == 0) 
[1]  4  5  6  7  8 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
# ROw 1 having value 0 and row 2 having value 1
> which(space[1,] == 0 & space[2,] == 1)
integer(0)

# Total number obtained from each case above:
> length(which(space[1,] == 1 & space[2,] == 1))
[1] 6

> length(which(space[1,] == 0 & space[2,] == 0))
[1] 10

> length(which(space[1,] == 1 & space[2,] == 0))
[1] 20

> length(which(space[1,] == 0 & space[2,] == 1))
[1] 0
```